# Use mutex to lock an object

Tags: c#, object, mutex

I have an app that creates an object that needs to be locked as this object creates an external hardware device object (via third party DLL) and the hardware device object can only be created once.  When multiple instances of this app are launched, only the first instance should be able to create this C# object.  The subsequence instances should see that the object  has been locked and object can not be created.  I used a mutex as this object creation occurs in multiple app instances (multiple processes).  The code doesn't lock with the mutex however.  Am I running multiple instances in which each one creates its own lock?

```
public sealed class MyObject
{
    private static MyObject _myObject;
    static ExtDeviceDriver devDrv;
    private readonly static Mutex mut = new Mutex();

    private MyObject()
    {
        mut.WaitOne();
        //Thread safe code here.
        devDrv = new ExtDeviceDriver();
    }

    ~MyObject()
    {
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    // object accessor
    public static MyObject GetMyObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myObject == null)
                _myObject = new MyObject();
            return _myObject;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might help on locking http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/c-use-monitor-lock-object-mutex-and-other-syn-objects-t1339503.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use named mutex ([See this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw29w7t1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

> Mutexes are of two types: local mutexes and named system mutexes. If
>   you create a Mutex object using a constructor that accepts a name, it
>   is associated with an operating-system object of that name. Named
>   system mutexes are visible throughout the operating system and can be
>   used to synchronize the activities of processes. You can create
>   multiple Mutex objects that represent the same named system mutex, and
>   you can use the OpenExisting method to open an existing named system
>   mutex.

So, try to use this [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to create a named Mutex. Besides you should check, whether it already exists with [Mutex.OpenExisting Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c41ybyt3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (Consider the example given in this very article; is tells how to check, create, utilize a named mutex).

**EDIT**

See [Mutex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx):

> You can use the WaitHandle.WaitOne method to request ownership of a
>   mutex. The thread that owns a mutex can request the same mutex in
>   repeated calls to WaitOne without blocking its execution. However, the
>   thread must call the ReleaseMutex method the same number of times to
>   release ownership of the mutex. The Mutex class enforces thread
>   identity, so a mutex can be released only by the thread that acquired
>   it.

And [Mutex Constructor (Boolean, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx), that says, that a bool argument must be set to:

> true to give the calling thread
>   initial ownership of the named system mutex if the named system mutex
>   is created as a result of this call; otherwise, false.

Comment: Thank you for your pointer. Is there a way to check that the mutex has been taken and abort (not spin and wait with mutex.WaitOne()) in the second app instance so this instance can move on to other things?

Comment: @Kevin Have a look at the `WaitOne` method overload list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.waitone(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Kevin Namely *WaitHandle.WaitOne Method (Int32)* - blocks your thread for certain amount of time and returns `false`, if it couldn't take it.

Comment: I changed the code to use: private Mutex mut = new Mutex(true, myMutex), call mut.WaitOne(), then call mut.ReleaseMutex() at the end to exit the critical section.  The 1st instance ran this thru and it was fine.  The 2nd instance hangs at mut.WaitOne().  The 1st instance has to run thru the above code one more time and passed it as it still has the mutex.  The 2nd instance then can execute pass mut.WaitOne().  It appears that the 1st instance did not release the mutex until the second run-thru.  Why's that?

Comment: The 2nd run of the 1st instance doesn't call mut.WaitOne() due to some code logic.  this means that that 1st instance call mut.WaitOne() once (during the 1st run) but has to call mut.ReleaseMutex() twice in order to release the mutex.

Comment: @Kevin You use `true` in constructor, that means, the thread, which creates the mutex, takes ownership over mutex without explicit call to `WaitOne`. So, if you make an extra call of `WaitOne`, you need to `Release` it twice. Read MSDN attentively. Besides, it is supposed to be a separate question...

Comment: The code above yields exception: "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." when the destructor executes code:    ~MyObject()
    {
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }   Why is that?  The codes are executed on the same main thread.

Comment: @Kevin it means that the thread from which you call `ReleaseMutex` does not own the mutex and has neither right no necessity to do that